# FFMPEG Combining Two Commands Into One

Tags: ffmpeg

Im currently trying to combine trim and delogo together, looked over a few tutorials but i just have no clue.

trim:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -t  00:00:10 -async 1 ouput.mp4
```

delogo:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1075:y=9:w=170:h=52" -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

I want to combine these two commands so i can run one execution which will do both within, instead of 2 separate commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -t 10 -vf "delogo=x=1075:y=9:w=170:h=52" -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, whats the reason for the `-async 1` removal?

Comment: One last Q; how would i add a logo overlay in there(watermark), i tried some formats such as before -vf after, between -c:a, after, tried those also by removing -i watermark.png, tried adding as quotation, using comma, followed other links but cant seem to get it right

`-i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=0:0"`